# Proper Commit Messages

Tags: commit, version-control, commit-message

What are commit messages for? I've always been writing them as an explanation of what I did, but I've recently gotten into a discussion about it with a colleague who writes commit messages explaining why he did. Which one is right, or is there another answer entirely?

NOTE: I have absolutely no idea if there is a "right" answer for this. As such, I've labeled it community wiki and will not accept an answer. Upvotes shall decide the winner :)

Answer (score 7):

As a personal preference, I can tell *what* was done by looking at the differences in the files directly. The *why* is the thing I can't infer from just looking at the actual changes.

If the changes are significant or complicated, then I would include not only the why, but also a brief overview of the *how*.

Comment: I view a commit message as an e-mail. The "what" is the subject line, maybe referencing a bug #, but should succinctly describe the change

The body of the commit message is the why.

Comment: Actually, looking at the diff tells you *how* it was done, the comments in the code and the issue tracking system should tell you *why*, and the commit message should tell you *what*, preferably along with a link to the issue tracking system. In my opinion, of course.

Comment: Some changes don't easily submit to "comments ... should tell you why": deleting rotten code, for example. Adding the "why" to the comments each time could end in an SCM-in-source-code scenario. Granted, sometimes it *does* make sense to add a comment explaining why the "obvious" approach of adding some code here would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are useful.  A quick description of what changed ("Adding length validation for AddUserForm") is easier than looking at a diff, especially if you're browsing multiple commits.  Why the change was made, what bug it fixed, etc. is obviously a very good thing to have, too.

Answer (score 1):

I use the commit message as an **[executive summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_summary)** of *what* was changed.

> Executive summary is a [...] short document that summarizes [...] in such a way that readers can rapidly become acquainted with a large body of material without having to read it all.

The *why* is documented somewhere else: an issue tracking system, requirements documentation, etc. I also include links from the commit message to the *why*, and vice versa.

Comment: Why is important - if you're not documenting it elsewhere, then put it in the commit message.

Comment: @theatrus, I absolutely agree, but for any medium-large project, commit messages are **not** the place to document your *why*.

Comment: @Dolph, I think commit messages are a *great* place to put code-whys, but I agree with you that it's a bad place to put project-whys. Example: "This code was breaking foo because it segfaulted on bar": good. "This feature is needed to support Joe from Foo Inc.": bad.

Answer (score 1):

Commit messages are what you make of them, but when there are hundreds of them for a particular file, or thousands for a project, you want to be able to scan through them looking for certain changes or the nature of the changes.  In effect, they are like code comments, and they need to be as helpful as possible, yet concise and pithy.  Maybe best to think of them as tweets - convey maximum meaning in a short space.

As somebody who's worked on large code bases spanning decades, and also smaller projects spanning a year or two, I've found nothing more infuriating when combing commit logs than messages like "oops" or "fixed bug".  If you fixed a bug, tell us which one (a bug number, at the very least).  It's all important for the inevitable forensics down the road.